# Select the result of a comparison in SQL statement

Tags: sql

How would I achieve the following:

```
select (1 < 2) as One, (1 > 2) as Two
```

so that it would yield the following results:

```
One     Two
-----------------
True    False
```

I'm using SQL Server but a cross DBMS example would be good.

Comment: Many people responded correctly, I just want to add that in non-brain-damaged engines like MySQL and PostgreSQL you'd write exactly as you have. Oracle and MSSQL apparently have the Boolean type but only internally (as the result of the comparison operators), but not as a datatype that can be returned from a `SELECT`. No idea why.

Comment: @Amadan try this for a reason - it's not in the ANSI SQL spec. Not even sql-2003 http://savage.net.au/SQL/

Comment: @Richard What's this then? http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#boolean%20type The problem as I understand is that people can't agree as to what the result of logical operations in NULL-extended trinary logic should be - but I think that's a bullshit argument, because you will de facto have the boolean type as the result of comparisons, and you will have NULL there, and it does need to be handled in some way - preventing that result from being directly returned is sweeping shit under the carpet, in my opinion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL server, you can use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement.

```
select (case when (1 < 2) then 'True' else 'False' end) as one,
       (case when (1 > 2) then 'True' else 'False' end) as two
from table
```

In the place of condition, you can use any variable or any column values too. Basically an expression.

Comment: With SQL Server you don't even need the FROM clause.

Comment: @Dave - yes, you are right. the `From` is to be used if the expression has any references to columns from table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Oracle you could do something like

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN 1 < 2 THEN
           'TRUE'
         ELSE
           'FALSE'
       END AS ONE,
       CASE
         WHEN 1 > 2 THEN
           'TRUE'
         ELSE
           'FALSE'
       END AS TWO
  FROM DUAL;
```

Note that Oracle doesn't have a BOOLEAN type in the database (as opposed to PL/SQL, which *does* have BOOLEAN's) so the case expressions return character strings.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement:

```
declare @value1 int, @value2 int
set @value1 = 1
set @value2 = 2

select
case when (@value1 < @value2) then 'True' else 'False' end as One
case when (@value1 > @value2) then 'False' else 'True' end as Two
from table
```

Depending on your need, you can hard code in the values, or you can do something similar to this for when you may want to change the values.  You could also combine the case statement into one column, or break it out for doing less than or equal type comparisons as well.